# Is there any way of not using my_init_method in the following code (that creates a custom post type)?

Tags: custom-post-types, php

Mike Schindel provided me this code long time ago:

```
<?php
/**
 * Create the Blocks custom post type and the Sections custom taxonomy
 */
add_action('init', 'my_init_method');

if (!class_exists('YourSite_Blocks')) {
    class YourSite_Blocks {
        static function on_load() {
            add_action('init',array(__CLASS__,'init'));
            add_filter('manage_blocks_posts_columns',
                array(__CLASS__,'manage_blocks_posts_columns'));
            add_filter('manage_posts_custom_column',
                array(__CLASS__,'manage_posts_custom_column'),10,2);
            add_action('restrict_manage_posts',
                array(__CLASS__,'restrict_manage_posts'));
        }
        // Register custom post types and custom taxonomies
        static function init() {
            register_post_type('blocks',array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Blocks' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Block' ),
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Block',
                    'edit_item' => 'Edit Block',
                    'new_item' => 'New Block',
                    'search_items' => 'Search Block',
                    'not_found' => 'No Blocks found',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Blocks found in trash',
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'taxonomies' => array( 'section'),
                'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
                'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'blocks','with_front'=>false),
                'menu_position' => 50,
            ));
            register_taxonomy('location','blocks',array(
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Locations' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Location' ),
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Location',
                    'edit_item' => 'Edit Location',
                    'new_item' => 'New Location',
                    'search_items' => 'Search Location',
                    'not_found' => 'No Location found',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Locations found in trash',
                    'all_items' => __( 'All Locations' ),
                ),
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'location' ),
            ));
            register_taxonomy('section','blocks',array(
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Sections' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Section' ),
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Section',
                    'edit_item' => 'Edit Section',
                    'new_item' => 'New Section',
                    'search_items' => 'Search Section',
                    'not_found' => 'No Sections found',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Sectionss found in trash',
                    'all_items' => __( 'All Sections' ),
                ),
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'section' ),
            ));
            // Add initial terms
            if (!get_option('yoursite-blocks-initialized')) {
                $terms = array(
                    'Intro',
                    'Tagline',
                    'Mainbar',
                    'Sidebar',
                    'Featured',
                    'Content',
                );
                foreach($terms as $term) {
                    if (!get_term_by('name',$term,'section')) {
                        wp_insert_term($term, 'section');
                    }
                }
                update_option('yoursite-blocks-initialized',true);
            }
        }
        // Arrange the position of elements in the table
        function manage_blocks_posts_columns($columns) {
            $columns = array(
                'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
                'title' => 'Name',
                'location_column' => 'Location',
                'section_column' => 'Section',
                'author' => 'Author',
                'date' => 'Date',
            );
            return $columns;
        }
        // Verify that we are indeed working with only the custom post type and use a switch statement to test against the column
        function manage_posts_custom_column( $column,$post_id ) {
            global $typenow;
            if ($typenow=='blocks') {
                $location_taxonomy = 'location';
                $section_taxonomy = 'section';
                switch ($column) {
                case 'location_column':
                    $location_column = get_the_terms($post_id,$location_taxonomy);
                    if (is_array($location_column)) {
                        foreach($location_column as $key => $location) {
                            $edit_link = get_term_link($location,$location_taxonomy);
                            $location_column[$key] = '<a href="'.$edit_link.'">' . $location->name . '</a>';
                        }
                        echo implode(' | ',$location_column);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'section_column':
                    $section_column = get_the_terms($post_id,$section_taxonomy);
                    if (is_array($section_column)) {
                        foreach($section_column as $key => $section) {
                            $edit_link = get_term_link($section,$section_taxonomy);
                            $section_column[$key] = '<a href="'.$edit_link.'">' . $section->name . '</a>';
                        }
                        echo implode(' | ',$section_column);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // Output multiple taxonomy filters
        function restrict_manage_posts() {

            // Only display these taxonomy filters on desired custom post_type listings
            global $typenow;
            if ($typenow == 'blocks') {

                // Create an array of taxonomy slugs you want to filter by - if you want to retrieve all taxonomies, could use get_taxonomies() to build the list
                $filters = array('location', 'section');

                foreach ($filters as $tax_slug) {
                    // Retrieve the taxonomy object
                    $tax_obj = get_taxonomy($tax_slug);
                    $tax_name = $tax_obj->labels->name;
                    // Retrieve array of term objects per taxonomy
                    $terms = get_terms($tax_slug);

                    // Output html for taxonomy dropdown filter
                    echo "<select name='$tax_slug' id='$tax_slug' class='postform'>";
                    echo "<option value=''>Show All $tax_name</option>";
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {
                        // Output each select option line, check against the last $_GET to show the current option selected
                        echo '<option value='. $term->slug, $_GET[$tax_slug] == $term->slug ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>' . $term->name .' (' . $term->count .')</option>';
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    YourSite_Blocks::on_load();
}
```

It worked perfectly until now.

I'm using a theme that seems to have a problem with the first line:

```
add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
```

Is there any way of modifying this code so that it can still work without that conflicting line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the error message being generated?

Also, to avoid conflicts, *all custom Theme functions, classes, options, constants, etc.* should be *prefixed uniquely*, e.g. using `theme-slug`.

It is highly likely that a generic function name like `my_init_method` is used by another Plugin or Theme. Try renaming it to `mytheme-slug_init_method`.

EDIT:

To implement, rename your function call from:

```
function my_init_method() {}
```

to:

```
function mytheme-slug_init_method() {}
```

Then, change your hook call from:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_init_method' );
```

to:

```
add_action( 'init', 'mytheme_init_method' );
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but I can't find `function my_init_method() {}` where it is? (and which slug should I add?)

Comment: Bennet By the way, this is the error message: `Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'my_init_method' was given in /home/aleche23/alexchen.info/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 395`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments to Chip, I think this is probably what you want:

`add_action( 'init', array( 'YourSite_Blocks', 'on_load' ) )`.

And remove `add_action( 'init', 'my_init_method' );`

What you want to do is call the on_load method of the YourSite_Blocks class every time wordpress loads. That's the method that takes care of registering all the post types and adding the actions and filters.